# Error creating matrix in r

Tags: r, matrix

I am trying to create a 256*256 matrix in R. Simple task I thought... If I create the data such that

```
aa=1:65536
z = matrix(bb,nrow=256,ncol=256,byrow=T)
```

I have the matrix I want e.g.

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] 
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5
```

and so on. However, I am not creating the "aa" data but reading it instead such that

```
aa = read.table("myfile.txt",header=F)
> aa[c(1:10),]
[1] 1513.708 1513.971 1514.067 1513.971 1513.875 1513.622 1513.524 1513.578 1513.577 1513.481
```

When I read aa, the data looks fine but when I try and turn it into a matrix, the matrix reads as

```
     [,1]          [,2]          [,3]          [,4]          [,5] 
[1,] Numeric,65536 Numeric,65536 Numeric,65536 Numeric,65536 Numeric,65536
```

and so on. Any idea why this is happening?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: How did you "turn it into a matrix". I'm guessing you did not use data.matrix() which would have been the right way. Looks to me that you looped through it and created a matrix of lists.

Comment: What class is aa? ( try `class(aa)` ).

Comment: @DWin You're spot on. That's how I created the matrix. Thanks to your answer I realise it wasn't the way to do it. I'll use data.matrix in the future.       @Joris Meys the class is `data.frame`

Comment: Guessed so. Then @DWins answer is the correct one. (or you could use `as.matrix()`, but that has a different default behaviour for factors.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note this paragraph in the 'Memory usage' section of `?read.table`:

```
 ‘read.table’ is not the right tool for reading large matrices,
 especially those with many columns: it is designed to read _data
 frames_ which may have columns of very different classes.  Use
 ‘scan’ instead for matrices.
```

Granted, your 256x265 matrix isn't *large* but `scan` still seems more appropriate.

```
aa <- matrix(scan("myfile.txt"), nrow=256, ncol=256, byrow=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the `sep=""` parameter to `read.table()`. With the sep-parameter you can define the separators for your file, which separators you can define and how you find in `?read.file`. Comment if there are any additional problems.

EDIT: can you copy-paste us a little of the file you are reading?

Comment: I have just realised that doing    `z=matrix(aa[c(1:65536),],nrow=256,ncol=256,byrow=T)` solved the problem although I'm not quite clear why I need to specify `aa[c(1:65536),]`

Comment: we need not the code you use but a part of your file to see the formatting, e.g. the first 100 characters of your file

Comment: Sorry, I'd pressed enter before finishing my previous comment.

Comment: No problem. Interesting, so you have 65536 columns now. Is that what you wanted? (Also note, that the `:` is complete range syntax, you can remove the `c()`.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for your very helpful comments. I had clearly made quite a few mistakes that I now understand how to avoid in the future.

Comment: sure anytime, repost if anything else